# Normalize time-series data before or after split of training and testing data?

Tags: time-series

I use a classification model on time-series data where I normalize the data before splitting the data into train and test. Now, I know that train and test data should be treated separately to prevent data leaking.  What could be the proper order of normalization steps here? Should I apply steps 1,2,3 separately to train and test after I split data with the help of a sliding window? I use a sliding window here to compare each hour (test) with its previous 24 hrs data (train). Here is the order that I am currently using in the pipeline.

1. Moving averages (mean)
2. Resampling every hour
3. Standardization
4. Split data into train and test using a sliding window (of a length 24 hrs (train) and slides every 1 hr (test))
5. Fit the model using train data
6. Predict using the test data

Comment: What do steps 1 and 2 mean? It's not clear for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Steps 1 and 2 can be done safely, you just should take into account that The moving average must use only past values: `X'i = mean(Xi, Xi-1, Xi-2, ..., Xi-n)`.

However, in step 3, the normalization/standardization parameters, like *max* and *min* if you are using **minmax scaler** or *mean* and *standard deviation* if you are using **standardization**, should be computed from the training data and should be applied to the whole dataset, so your pipeline would be something like this

1. Moving average (using only past values)
2. Resampling every hour
3. Split data into train and test.
4. Get standardization parameters from the train data *(mean and std)*.
5. Standardize the whole dataset (train and test) using the parameters computed in 4.
6. Fit the model using train data
7. Predict using the test data

Comment: First is a typical smoothing technique used in time-series data and second is a typical downsampling technique where we take the mean of the values at every hour. I ended up using the following where I move step-3 inside the split like the following. `sc = StandardScaler()`
`X_train = sc.fit_transform(X_train)`
`X_test = sc.transform (X_test)`

Comment: About your step 3 implementation, it looks good to me.

Comment: Yes, it does. As the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.rolling.html) says, "By default, the result is set to the right edge of the window".

Comment: Thank you. I apply moving averages to both train and test for every 100 hours using the `Pandas` function `df.rolling('100').mean()`. Does this satisfy your past-values condition?

Comment: If your data is non-stationary applying scaler.fit_transform() on training data and fit() on test data will create problems.  For example, if your data has a general upward trend then high values in your test set will not scale correctly.  You can try applying transformations to your data to help with the non-stationary issue.